# Javascript $.Map() & Math.Max.Appy() to find maximum height

Tags: javascript, jquery

- following code is working code used to find maximum height
- `$.fn.` is used to add this method as jQuery Plugin.
- `$.Map()` return new array
- `Math.Max.Apply` return max number from array

  ```
  $.fn.tallest = function(outer, margins) {

      var fn = outer ? "height" : "outerHeight";

      return Math.max.apply(Math, $.map(this, function(el){return $(el)[fn](margins);}));

  };

  //var images=jquery(img 1.jpg, img 2.jpg, img 3.ipg, img 4.jpg);
  var slidesHeight = images.tallest();
  ```
- In this I have trouble understanding below line, but do understand
  how .Map() works.
  `$.map(this, function(el) {return $(el)[fn](margins);})`
- `$(el)[fn](margins)` //Especially how this line return height attribute of image.

Comment: It looks like you're missing square brackets in your expression. It should probably be `$(el)[fn]`.

Comment: You can access an objects properties either with dot notation or bracket notation. See http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(el)[fn]` is just another way of calling a method in `$(el)` whose name is not known in advance.

`$(el)[fn](margins)` is the same as having `$(el).height(margins)` or `$(el).outerHeight(margins)` depending on the value of the `fn` which depends on the value of the argument `outer`.

When `outer` is non-falsy, `fn` will be `"outerHeight"` and the above statement will be equivalent to `$(el).outerHeight(margins)`

When `outer` is falsy, `fn` will be `"height"` and the above statement will be equivalent to `$(el).height(margins)`

Comment: `$(el).fn(margins)` is a bit misleading IMO.

Comment: @MattWhipple - Ofcourse it does not translate in the real sense. But from a code-reading point of view, it is easier to explain it this way.

Comment: @techfoobar, yes my comment was written in an earlier revision when there was an apparent implication that `$(el).fn` would work and therefore was interchangeable with square bracket notation.  It is not relevant with the edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

*Edited to incorporate Felix Kling's note.

Ok, let's break it down

```
$.map(this, function(el){return $(el)[fn](margins);})
```

1. `$.map` is a function that iterates over a collection and performs the passed in function to each element within the collection and returns an array with all the results.
   For example:

   ```
   $.map([1,2], function(i) {return i + 1})
   [2, 3]
   ```
2. The `this` refers to the collection that the jQuery collection `$.fn.tallest()` is working against.
   For example:

   ```
   $('tr').tallest() // => this would refer to all the tr's within the dom
   ```
3. `$(el)[fn]`
   In JavaScript, you can either invoke a function bound to a receiver with the regular dot notation, such as `$(e1).height` or you can use bracket notation as the example you provided does: `$(e1)['height']`.
4. `$(e1)[fn](margins)`
   `margins` is the passed in argument to the function `height()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I would refrain from calling `$(el)[fn]` "*array* notation". This does not have anything to do with arrays and it might confuse less experienced readers. The official name is "**bracket** notation".